# Convert an expression to a Function

Tags: function-construction

I need a function which can take an expression and return a pure function based on the symbols in the expression. The symbols might have values so must be protected from evaluation. It is probably easiest to give an example:

I would like to evaluate something like

```
x = y = 1;
extractPureFunction[Sin[Pi x^2] + y]
```

and obtain

```
Function[{x, y}, Sin[Pi x^2] + y]
```

or

```
(Sin[Pi #1^2] + #2) &
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just curious: how would you ever going to use the `Function` if you don't know in which order the variables may end up? I mean, they are sorted alphabetically, so if I swapped x and y the *structure* of the original function would be the same, but the resulting `Function` would behave differently.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, good question! Essentially I want to be able to transform an expression to a form which matches the pattern `func_[vars__]`. I wouldn't be using `func` by itself (despite the wording of my question, the pure function alone is not the final goal)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What about taking the symbols not in heads that haven't got the `NumericFunction` or `Constant` or `Protected` attribute (thanks @OleksandrR) and that are in the `` Global` `` context? The condition can easily be tweaked, and also one can easily add options on attributes, contexts, or extra symbols to be included or always excluded of argmuents

```
SetAttributes[{extractPureFunction, condition}, HoldFirst];
condition[i_Symbol] := 
  FreeQ[Attributes@i, NumericFunction | Constant | Protected] && 
   Context@i == "Global`";


extractPureFunction[expr_] := 
 Union@Cases[Unevaluated@expr, 
     i_Symbol?condition :> Hold[i], {0, Infinity}]~Thread~Hold /. 
  Hold[vars_] :> Function[vars, expr]


extractPureFunction[Sin[x] x + Pi + y - Total@Through@{Tan, ArcTan}[E]]
```

> Function[{x, y},Sin[x] x + [Pi] + y - Total[Through[{Tan, ArcTan}[E]]]]

Note, this doesn't respect inner scoping constructs so variables from inner `Function`s or `Module`s for example would get listed as arguments

Comment: I was puzzling over whether to post this myself, but I forgot to consider the `Attributes`--good catch. Also, your use of `Thread` is nice (I had used a `{Flat, HoldAll}` function).

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrR. This kind of manipulations are never easy, at least for me, I don't do them often

Comment: Oh, and also: setting `Heads -> True` for `Cases` might be a useful addition, depending on how you want things like `Derivative[x][y]` to behave.

Comment: Thinking a bit more about the attributes: isn't it enough just to check for `Protected`? If something has that then it can't have been meant as a variable in the first place. `Constant`, on the other hand, just means its derivative is zero, which may or may not be relevant here.

Comment: @OleksandrR. that's probably a good idea. However, there's a ``Cases[Names["System`*"], i_ /; FreeQ[Attributes@i, Protected]]`` long list of unprotected System symbols to think about. Edited to add that check but I'm not sure if the others are redundant

Comment: @OleksandrR. but what about formal symbols? We are leaving them out now

Comment: Okay, so the context check is still needed to exclude the various display forms/operators and `$*` variables. I think formal symbols should be excluded from this to avoid messing up objects they're used in (like `DifferentialRoot`s). Ideally they would be used more widely, and then techniques like this would be safer: consider `extractPureFunction[x = Function[{y}, y]]`. `y` gets renamed away and is safe, but you end up with a function with an extraneous parameter that has to be supplied. I'm just coming to realise that this question is a lot more difficult than it seems!

Comment: This is just what I need, thank you. I'm not bothered about it not respecting inner scoping constructs - in general I expect the expression to be quite simple.

Answer (score 16):

Well, since you defined x=y=1, evaluation semantics will make it very difficult to get at them inside your mathematical expression.

The general issue is one of extracting the variables. I show a way to go about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846644/utility-to-extract-variables-from-an-expression). With getAllVariables as defined therein, one can then do as below.

```
extractPureFunction[expr_] := Module[{vars, func},
  vars = Cases[getAllVariables[expr],_Symbol];
  func[vars, expr] /. func -> Function]
```

Test:

```
In[38]:= extractPureFunction[Sin[Pi t^2] + w]

(* Out[38]= Function[{w, t}, w + Sin[Pi*t^2]] *)
```

Comment: `extractPureFunction[Sin[Pi t^2] + w[[1]]]`

Comment: @Verde Fixed, more or less. That is to say, it will now only accept "variables" that are symbols. I'm sure it's still not bullet proof.

Comment: Sounds fair enough :)

Comment: I like your `getAllVariables`. Shame that we need something like ``Internal`LocalizedBlock`` to actually use most of those expressions as variables, though...

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Unfortunately I really need something that works when the variables have values. Your `getAllVariables` is definitely one for the toolbag though.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau it seems you need wrap Union around vars to get it to work on say x Sin[x y]

Comment: @chris Yes, that Union usage sounds about right.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my approach, which is similar to Rojo's in some ways.  I'm taking the simple approach that any symbol not in `` System` `` is a user variable.  (Adjust the condition as needed.)

```
SetAttributes[extractPureFunction, HoldAll]
SetAttributes[heldVariables, HoldAll]

heldVariables[e_] := 
 Thread[Union[
   Cases[HoldForm[e], 
    s_Symbol /; Context[s] =!= "System`" :> Hold[s], Infinity]], Hold]

extractPureFunction[e_] := 
 ReleaseHold[Function @@@ Thread[{heldVariables[e], Hold[e]}, Hold]]
```

Here's the test case:

```
x = y = 1;
extractPureFunction[Sin[Pi x^2] + y]

(*  ==> Function[{x, y}, Sin[\[Pi] x^2] + y]  *)
```

Answer (score 8):

Since I put something together to do this this past fall, I guess I should throw my hat in the ring, too. I think it is close to water tight, but I can't be sure.

First, we need to determine what the variables in the expression are

```
Clear[GetVariables]
SetAttributes[GetVariables, HoldFirst];
GetVariables[expr_, f_:Identity, excludedContexts:{__String}:{"System`"}]:=
Cases[Unevaluated[expr], 
  a_Symbol /; 
    !(   MemberQ[excludedContexts, Context[a]] 
      || MemberQ[Attributes[a], Locked | ReadProtected]
     ) :> f[a], 
  {0, Infinity}
]//DeleteDuplicates
```

Unlike the others, it provides flexibility in specifying which `Contexts` are to be excluded, and removes from consideration both [`Locked`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Locked.html) and [`ReadProtected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReadProtected.html) symbols.  As a flaw, it only looks at symbols, so it won't distinguish between `Subscript[a,1]` and `Subscript[a,2]`. The second parameter here is special, it allows us to put wrappers, such as `Hold`, around an accepted symbol to prevent its execution.

Second, we need to use it:

```
ClearAll[MakeFunction]
Options[MakeFunction]={VariableList->Automatic};
SetAttributes[MakeFunction, HoldFirst];

(* This first form allows pure functions to be used *)
MakeFunction[afcn_Function, opts:OptionsPattern[]]:= afcn

MakeFunction[fexpr_, opts:OptionsPattern[] ]:= 
Module[{vars},
vars = If[OptionValue[VariableList]===Automatic,
             (* GetVariables returns {Hold[x_] ..} we want Hold[{x_ ..}] *)
             Distribute[Sort[GetVariables[fexpr, Hold]], Hold],
             OptionValue[Automatic, Automatic, VariableList, Hold]
           ];
Function @@ Join[vars, Hold[fexpr]]
]
```

There are a couple things to notice here. First, it allows for pure functions to be passed to it. This is merely for convenience as it makes it more broadly applicable. Second, the option `VariableList` allows the user to specify what the variables actually are because if we know them already, we might as well use them. This has the added benefit of allowing the user to change the order of the parameters which defaults to lexical sorting.

```
Through @ (MakeFunction /@ {x^2, Sin[x y^2], x + I y})[3, 4]
(* {9, Sin[48], 3 + 4 I} *)

Through @ (MakeFunction[#, VariableList -> {y, x}] & /@ {x^2, Sin[x y^2], x + I y})[3, 4]
(* {16, Sin[36], 4 + 3 I} *)
```

Comment: @SimonWoods thanks. Admittedly, it isn't entirely my work, Leonid looked at it a while back and had some suggestions.

Comment: @SimonWoods it was needed to create a function which allowed me to plot along an arbitrary $\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ function using `Plot`, and I desperately needed the ability to make an expression executable.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure this is far from watertight, but it seems to work for the expression I've tried. The hard bit was preventing Mathematica from evaluating the symbols prematurely.

```
toFunction[exp_] := Module[{exp1, syms},
  exp1 = ToExpression[exp, InputForm, Hold];
  syms = SymbolName /@ Pick[#, Not[NumericQ[Unevaluated[#]]] & /@ #] &@
    ReleaseHold[{Unevaluated /@ Level[exp1, {-1}, Hold]}];
  ToExpression["Function[ {" <> StringJoin[Riffle[syms, ","]] <> "}," <> exp <> "]"]]
```

Example:

```
a = 2;
ff = toFunction["Sin[abc a+b+Pi/5]^4-5"]

(* Function[{abc, a, b}, Sin[abc a + b + \[Pi]/5]^4 - 5] *)
```

Edit: I missed the fact that the argument was given as an expression and not as a string. In that case you could do something like

```
SetAttributes[toFunction, HoldAll]
toFunction[exp_] := Module[{syms},
  syms = SymbolName /@ Pick[#, Not[NumericQ[Unevaluated[#]]] & /@ #] &@
    ReleaseHold[{(Unevaluated /@ Level[Hold[exp], {-1}, Hold])}];
  ToExpression[
   "Function[ {" <> StringJoin[Riffle[syms, ","]] <> "}," <> 
    ToString[Unevaluated[exp], InputForm] <> "]"]]
```

Comment: Lateral thinking, I like it! The code needs a `Union` or `DeleteDuplicates` to catch multiple occurrences of the same symbol.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my approach. It works by picking out only the non-heads and then filtering out the built-in constants like `π`, `E` and numbers.

```
ClearAll[toPureFunction]
SetAttributes[toPureFunction, HoldAll]
toPureFunction[expr_] := With[{constantQ = MemberQ[Attributes[#], Constant] &}, 
    Module[{vars, func}, 
        vars = Quiet[
            Cases[
                HoldForm@expr // Level[#, {-1}, Unevaluated] &, 
                x_Symbol?(OwnValues[#] =!= {} || ! constantQ[#] &) :> Hold@x], 
            OwnValues::sym];

        Quiet[Function[Evaluate@DeleteDuplicates@vars, expr] // ReleaseHold, Function::flpar]
    ]
]
```

Here's the output on some of the examples used in the question and other answers:

```
toPureFunction[Sin[π x^2] + y]
(* Function[{x, y}, Sin[π x^2] + y] *)

toPureFunction[Sin[x] x + Pi + y - Total@Through@{Tan, ArcTan}[E]]
(* Function[{x, y}, Sin[x] x + π + y - Total[Through[{Tan, ArcTan}[E]]]] *)
```

Comment: Nice. I must say I like the pragmatism of `Quiet`ing the warnings rather than doing code gymnastics to avoid them. A minor point is that your approach removes any `Hold` in the original expression.