# How to set a function as a parameter?

Tags: functions, conditional

In case I want to know whether a given function $f(t)$ have some property, I tried to write something like this:

```
IsSuppFun[f_[t_]] := Resolve[
ForAll[t, 0 <=t <= 2&&t\[Element] Reals,
 f[t] + D[f[t], {t, 2}] >= 0]]
```

Which means, if the given function satisfies the condition:
$f(t)+f''(t)\geq 0$ for all  $0\leq t\leq 2$, then return TRUE, else return False.

The problem is that it is not work as I supposed, for example, if I define

```
F[t_]:=t^2-3
```

then the output is:

```
IsSuppFun[-3 + t^2]
```

If I separate the code as

```
Resolve[ForAll[t, 0 <= t <= 2 Pi && t \[Element] Reals, F[t] + F''[t] >= 0]]
```

Which will get the Right Answer!

Where did I go wrong?

Solution is use the HoldAll attribute for the function IsSuppFun, Please see below for the answer!

---

there is my another problem in the same line:
If I have tried to add another condition as:

```
SetAttributes[IsSuppFun, HoldAll]
IsSuppFun[f_[t_]] := 
Resolve[ForAll[t, 0 <= t <= 2 && t \[Element] Reals, (f[t] + D[f[t], {t, 2}] >= 0)&&(f[0]==f[2])]]
```

then with the same test function:

```
F[t_] := t^2 - 3
```

the output is not as desired True or False, but as:

```
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ForAll]\), \(t\)]\(! \((0 <= t <= 2 &&  t \[Element] Reals)\)\)\)
```

---

May be I should change the last question as (to make things clear and simple):

```
SetAttributes[{IsSuppFun}, HoldAll]
IsSuppFun[f_[t_]] := Resolve[
ForAll[t,
0<= t <= 2 && t \[Element] Reals,
f[1] >= 0]
]
```

with the test function as:

```
F[t_] := Sin[t]
```

then the output of

```
IsSuppFun[F[t]]
```

is True; But if I have change it as

```
SetAttributes[{IsSuppFun}, HoldAll]
IsSuppFun[f_[t_]] := Resolve[
ForAll[t,
0<= t <= 2 && t \[Element] Reals,
f[1] <= 0]
]
```

Then the same test function gives neither True nor False. (I Suppose it False!) Why?

Comment: I think the problem is specifying the function's argument in `IsSuppFun`. Try : `bigF[t_] = t^2 - 3; IsSuppFun[bigF]`.

Comment: van abel, I think you are still confusing the second and third arguments of `ForAll` perhaps?  In your added example you are essentially doing: `Resolve[ForAll[t, 0 <= t <= 2 && t \[Element] Reals, False]]` because `F[0]==F[2]` is `False`.

Answer (score 6):

This answer intends to answer both parts of the question. Originally it answered only the first part. Below is the original answer. Scroll down for the second part.

---

I interchanged the third and second argument of ForAll and gave the function IsSuppFun attribute HoldAll, and it worked!

So I wrote

```
SetAttributes[IsSuppFun, HoldAll]
IsSuppFun[f_[t_]] := 
 Resolve[
  ForAll[
   t,
   0 <= t <= 2 ,
   f[t] + D[f[t], {t, 2}] >= 0
   ]
  ]

(*testcase*)

f[t_] := t^4
```

Then

```
IsSuppFun[f[x]]
```

Evaluates to True.

---

Second part

I removed the `t \[Element] Reals`, because it seemed redundant, or possibly wrong syntax. As it turned out, the new function worked.

```
SetAttributes[IsSuppFunGE, HoldAll]
IsSuppFunGE[f_[t_]] :=
  Resolve[ForAll[t, 0 <= t <= 2, f[1] >= 0]];

(* testcases*)
f[t_] := Sin[t];
g[t_] := Sin[t] - 2;
h[t_] := Cos[t] + 1;
```

Given these definitions,

```
{IsSuppFunGE[f[x]] , IsSuppFunGE[g[x]], IsSuppFunGE[h[x]]}
```

evaluates to

{True, False, True}

The question may arise if Mathematica is still using real numbers, as this is now not specified. The fact that the expression

```
Resolve[ForAll[t, 0 <= t <= 4, t != Pi]]
```

evaluates to False, may add confidence that it does indeed use real numbers (already).

Comment: Jacob, you can select your block of code in the editor and click the `{ }` symbol above it to format your code.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks!

Comment: Don't miss this:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Yes, I have made some mistake in the first edition, in which I have misplace the second and third parameter of ForAll.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks, I have checked it out. Now, as our answers are equivalent (I guess `t \[Element] Reals` only makes a difference if it is put before the inequalities), I suppose I should delete my answer. Correct?

Comment: @Jacob no, don't delete your answer.  van abel says mine's not working right so this isn't done yet.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok. Haha, note my inline code (using your editing help :) )

Comment: that's great format the question, but please help me to solve another question, which I have added in the original one.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to get what you want by setting a Hold attribute on your function:

```
SetAttributes[IsSuppFun, HoldAll]

IsSuppFun[f_[t_]] := 
 Resolve[ForAll[t, 0 <= t <= 2 && t \[Element] Reals, f[t] + D[f[t], {t, 2}] >= 0]]

f[t_] := t^2 - 3

IsSuppFun[f[t]]
```

> False

Comment: That works, Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, there still some problem, if I replace f by F in the test case, then the output has changed!

Comment: @vanabel your comment got cut off -- I changed `F` to `f` just as a matter of habit, but I forgot to try it the other way first.  I'll do that now.

Comment: @van abel it seems to still work the same for me.  Perhaps you could to do a `ClearAll[IsSuppFun, f, F, t]` and test it again?

Comment: Yes, I have tested again, it works for me too! Thanks, but there is another problem, if I have tried to add a condition to the third parameter, why it not works?
:(f[t] + D[f[t], {t, 2}] >= 0) && (f[0] == f[2])

Comment: @vanabel please add the example that fails, and the output you expect, to you question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6170/discussion-between-van-abel-and-mr-wizard)

Answer (score 0):

I would use this [Convert an expression to a Function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/convert-an-expression-to-a-function) as follows

```
 IsSuppFun[F_] := Module[{t,f= extractPureFunction[F]}, Resolve[
      ForAll[t, 0 <=t <= 2&&t\[Element] Reals,
      f[t] + D[f[t], {t, 2}] >= 0]]]
```

so that I don't have to worry about which variable is used.

The credit for the `extractPureFunction` that I use goes to Daniel Lichtblau