# How to make a function that evaluates an expression?

Tags: functions, evaluation

I'm trying to make a function where the input is an expression, but somehow it just won't be evaluated. For example, this little function doesn't work:

```
test[exp_] := Module[{x}, NestList[Function[x, exp], 2, 3]]
test[x^2]
(* {2, x^2, x^2, x^2} *)
```

And I would really like this output:

```
NestList[Function[x, x^2], 2, 3]
(* {2, 4, 16, 256} *)
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Try `NestList[ #^2 &, 2, 3]`

Comment: as @Artes points out: `test[exp_] := NestList[exp, 2, 3]; test[#^2 &]` does the trick? Or following your investigation `test[Function[x,x^2]]`

Comment: b.t.w. welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it
too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I would really like the input to be test[x^2] or test[2x+5], and not test[Function[x,x^2]]. Isn't that possible?

Comment: the best I can give you right now is `test[x^2,x]`:)

Comment: @SimonLausen it is via `extractPureFunction`; see below.

Comment: Something to think about: It's not worth writing several lines of code that relies on a more complicated function (e.g., `extractPureFunction`) just because you don't want to write it as `test[#^2&]` or `test[x^2,x]`. The saner thing to do in such cases would be to adopt the style that results in shorter and cleaner coding.

Comment: @rm-rf  but its ok to address the explicit request of the OP isn't it? ;-) (well its not so great if it just involves copying someone else's code I admit!)

Comment: @chris My comment wasn't about your answer... It was just a general advice for the OP that being very inflexible in syntax (unless they have a very good reason for it) can often lead to unnecessary code bloat for no tangible gain. In this case, it's the difference between a one-liner and 10-15 liner, depending on how you count your lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question (and one that has bitten me in the past:)
The reason for your troubles is the ways scoping of `Function` works.
That's easiest to demonstrate with module however.

```
Module[{x},x]
(*x$642*)
```

You see that instead of `x` `x$nnn` was returned. For more info I recommend reading [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BlocksComparedWithModules.html).

Block has the expected behavior by the way:

```
Block[{x},x]
(*x*)
```

How about function? The file states:
[image: help file]

A small test

```
test[exp_] := Function[x, exp]
test[x^2]
(*Function[x$, x^2]*)
```

So we see that the formal parameters of function have been renamed to `x$` and no longer match the `x` you have put in. Here are some solutions:

### Pass the function to your method

As has been suggested in the comments, you can pass the function as the argument.

```
ClearAll[test];
test[f_] := Module[{x}, NestList[f, 2, 3]]
test[#^2 &]
test[Function[x, x^2]]

(* ==> {2, 4, 16, 256} *)    
(* ==> {2, 4, 16, 256} *)
```

### Pass the variables along with the expression

```
ClearAll@test
test[exp_, vars_] := Function[Evaluate@vars, exp]
test[x^2, x]
(*Function[x, x^2]*)
```

Or inserted into your original example

```
test[exp_, vars_] := NestList[Function[Evaluate@vars, exp], 2, 3]
test[x^2, x]
(*{2, 4, 16, 256}*)
```

Oh and if you give your function the `HoldAll` attribute, then it will not be bothered by existing assignments to `x`

```
SetAttributes[test, HoldAll]
test[exp_, vars_] := NestList[Function[vars, exp], 2, 3]
x = 5
test[x^2, x]
(*{2, 4, 16, 256}*)
```

Comment: Hey, you've almost made it to the first page! congrats!

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help. My problem is solved. Have made my little function, that will save me a lot of time. Ajasja: I see your point, but the function I gave you was just an example of what was troubling me... Thank you again everybody!

Answer (score 4):

Since @Artes does not seem to want to write up his answer, let me explain why you attempt almost works but not quite.

This works

```
  test[exp_] := NestList[exp, 2, 3];
  test[Function[x,x^2]];

  (* {2, 4, 16, 256} *)
```

That doesn't

```
  test[exp_] := Module[{x}, NestList[Function[x, exp], 2, 3]]
  test[x^2]
```

because, within the `Function`, `x` is a local variable (say `x$123`) which does not match the one involved in the argument of `test` when you call `test[x^2]`.

**Without pure functions**

So if you really want to be able to use a formal expression (rather than a pure function) as an argument to `test`, you could use the function `extractPureFunction` that was implemented and discussed in this [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/convert-an-expression-to-a-function) as follows

```
  test[exp_] := Module[{ff=extractPureFunction[exp]}, NestList[ff, 2, 3]]
```

so that

```
  test[x^2]; test[Sin[y]]; test[Sin[x]+x+4];
```

works. But keep in mind this construction is not bullet proof: for instance

```
  test[x+y]
```

doesn't work (because it identifies a function of two parameters `x` and `y`).

As I find the `extractPureFunction` quite useful (I have it in my init.m file) I repeat it here (with as a bonus the `getAllVariables` function  that it uses). The credit goes to Daniel Lichtblau I believe(?)

```
 headlist = {Or, And, Equal, Unequal, Less, LessEqual, Greater, GreaterEqual, Inequality};
 getAllVariables[f_?NumericQ] := Sequence[]
 getAllVariables[{}] := Sequence[]
 getAllVariables[t_] /; MemberQ[headlist, t] := Sequence[]
 getAllVariables[ll_List] :=Flatten[Union[Map[getAllVariables[#] &, ll]]]
 getAllVariables[Derivative[n_Integer][f_][arg__]] :=
 getAllVariables[{arg}]
 getAllVariables[f_Symbol[arg__]] :=Module[{fvars},
    If[MemberQ[Attributes[f], NumericFunction] || MemberQ[headlist, f],
       fvars = getAllVariables[{arg}],(*else*)fvars = f[arg]]; fvars]
 getAllVariables[other_] := other

 extractPureFunction[expr_] := 
 Module[{vars, func}, vars = getAllVariables[expr];
 If[Length[vars] > 1, vars = Union[vars]];
 func[vars, expr] /. func -> Function]
```

Comment: `because, within the Module, x is a local variable (say x$123) which does not match the one involved in the argument of test when you call test[x^2]`
I think that `Module` is not at fault here, but that `Function` renames it's formal parameters anyway.

Comment: @Ajasja you are most certainly right.