# Assign variables automatically to a function

Tags: assignment

Lets consider that I've this function:

```
fn = a*x^2 + b*x + c;
```

The idea here is to assign automatically the variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `x` to a function so it becomes something like that:

```
fn[x_,a_,b_,c_] := a*x^2 + b*x + c
```

In order to do this I've tried to extract the varibles from `fn` using `Variables`:

```
Sort@Variables@fn
```

> {a, b, c, x}

Then in order to apply it to the function `fn` I do the following:

```
fn1@Variables@fn /. List -> Sequence
```

> fn1[a, b, c, x]

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to add the `Blank`s to the former expression in order to have `fn1[a_,b_,c_,x_]`?

> One of my fail attempt to do this was to use `Blank@#&/@Sort@Variables@fn` but it's obviously not working.

- One other point is that if you consider that you've found a way to automaticly have `fn1[a_,b_,c_,x_]`, how to assign the value of `fn` to `fn1[a_,b_,c_,x_]` without having the `fn1[a_,b_,c_,x_] is protected` message?

Comment: I don't think that going this way is a good idea. It is possible to do technically, but I don't see how you can make this semantically robust. Either you do it fully automatically, but then you don't know neither the number of resulting variables nore their ordering. Or you have some manual step, but then it makes sense to just simply define the function the way you want it, from the start.

Comment: mhm, if there is no way to do it automatically and robust it would be as you say easier to define the function with its variables directly. I just wondered if there was a lazy way to assign variables without typing them.

Comment: I think the same effect wil be obtained with this type of function definition: `Function[{x1,x2...},body]`. And will be definitely simpler.

Comment: This is strongly related (perhaps even a duplicate) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/convert-an-expression-to-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
fn = a*x^2 + b*x + c;
Clear[fn1];
autofunc[fn_] := 
 ToString[
   fn1[
    ToExpression /@ 
      Apply[StringJoin, 
       With[{var = ToString /@ Sort@Variables@fn}, 
        Transpose@Append[{var}, Table["_", {Length@var}]]], 2] /. 
     List -> Sequence]] <> ":= " <> ToString[fn, InputForm]

autofunc[fn]
ToExpression@autofunc[fn]
fn1[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> "fn1[a_, b_, c_, x_]:= c + b*x + a*x^2"
>
> 27

(I didn't say it was pretty..)

You have to evaluate it to see the number of variables in the new function (which is displayed as a "string"). Also `Clear[fn1]` is important in this case. With a bit more playing around I'm sure I could work out a way to automate the naming of the new function.

As others have said this may not be the best way to go about this...

Comment: Might not be pretty but I like it! Thanks!

Comment: To some who might find that answer useful I would recommend to use `{var = ToString /@ Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Cases[fn, _Symbol, Infinity]}` instead of `{var = ToString /@ Sort@Variables@fn}` so it works with every functions (& not only polynomials).