# Programatically adding/retaining comments within a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, conversion

Is it possible to convert the following list of strings to computable numbers with the comments preserved?

```
 str = {{{"8.0,1034(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q *)"}, {"8.0,1035(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q *)"}, 
         {"8.0,1037(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q *)"}, {"8.0,1038(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q *)"},   
         {"8.0,1039(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q *)"}, {"8.0,1040(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q *)"}},  
        {{"8.0,886(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q  *)"}, {"8.0,889 (*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q *)"},   
         {"8.0,891(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q  *)"}, {"8.0,894 (*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q  *)"},   
         {"8.0,896(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q  *)"}, {"8.0,899 (*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q  *)"}}}
```

I'm after something like:

```
strc = {{{8.0,1034(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q *)},....
```

Perhaps there is a way involving programatically adding the comments back onto the numbers after the numbers have been converted to an expression?  Any Suggestions?

Comment: To do this robustly (expressions of any type) I believe you will need to parse the strings, and that was done very nicely in answer to this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17648/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I really like your link (+1), but I disagree that you need to parse strings. To get the string in the first place is hard to do programmatically (and is not addressed by Leonid). In case quotes are present in the expression, we cannot simply put ""'s around it. In case comments are present, we cannot resort to ToString, as it would delete the comments and destroy formatting. I have looked at front end stuff like CopyToClipBoard a while ago but I think I was unable to make a function that would "put quotes around an expression in a smart way", maybe I should ask a question about it.

Comment: However, getting the cell expression programmatically is easy, as shown in my answer below. Also see my answer [here, in your linked Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26195/4330) ,to see how we can also use this to delete comments and keep our formatting. (also @Kuba)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you can also get the string from the cell expression using `ToString[NotebookRead[Cells[CellTags -> "targetCell"][[1]]][[1, 
   1]], InputForm]`, but I guess that should feel indirect.

Comment: @Jacob Good points, and +1 on your answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can start with that.

```
StringCases["8.0,1034(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q *)", 
 x__ ~~ y : ("(*" ~~ ___ ~~ "*)") :> {x, y}]
```

> {{"8.0,1034", "(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q *)"}}

And You can do with the first elements what You need.

**Edit**

I can not be passive after Jacob's remarks :) Following solution is based on his but simplified in order to avoid complicated procedures. I have also taken into account his comments to this post.

```
CellPrint[Cell[#, "Input"]] &@
 BoxData[ToBoxes[str] /. 
   x_String?(StringMatchQ[#, 
        "\"*" ~~ Verbatim["(*"] ~~ ___ ~~ Verbatim["*)\""]] &) :> 
    StringTake[x, {2, -2}]]
```

Definitely it works and is simple as it can be. I'm not sure why  `CellPrint[Cell[#, "Input"]] &@ BoxData[RowBox[{"{expr(*comm*)}"}]]` gives us what we need. I hope Jacob Akkerboom will tell us more.

Comment: +1 `y : ("(*" ~~ ___ ~~ "*)")` is nice.

Comment: Pff Kuba, I helped you twice, and now you are stealing my points with impressive but weak magic :P. Note that `StringMatchQ["()", ("(*" ~~ ___ ~~ "*)")]`-> True ;). You might as well have left out the asterix (*), it has special meaning in string pattern matching. I'm kidding, I shouldn't care about points, but please also see my answer :). (@DavidCarraher)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I'm aware of that :). But it is why I've started with "You can start.." :p. Definitely it is not general solution. About Your answer - please give me some time to study it, I was quite busy. :) I'm going to comment it soon.

Comment: Cool, looking forward to that :). Anyway the pattern you are really after is  `"(" ~~ _?(MatchQ[#, "*"] &) ~~ ___ ~~ _?(MatchQ[#, "*"] &) ~~ ")"`.

Comment: The above is nicer with Verbatim I guess, but I can't really show it as this will just format my code instead of display what I want. So we want something like "(" ~~ Verbatim["*"] ~~ ___ ~~...

Comment: Wow Kuba, now this good stuff, +1 :). Much more practical than my answer, using the existing RowBox works fine, you make good use of its flexibility. Your (replacement) rule can be written a bit shorter, I'll suggest an edit, but its up to you what you like best :).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom The shorther the better. Since I can't give You half of this votes I promise I will watch Your posts more often. :) The pattern could end with ~~"*\"" in case where comments are not in the end of strings like here. But it is one of improvements, many can be done :)

Comment: @Kuba Feel free, I was only joking. But I do find voting systems very interesting, as I think a good reputation system can really help a community. Anyway, do you know the menu option Cell>Show Expression? You will see Cell, Boxdata and RowBox there :). ToBoxes is a nice function. Did you also see the [link](mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17648/121) by Mr.Wizard? That looks very interesting as well. Leonid only got 3 upvotes. To get back to votes, I believe Mr.Wizard once said Leonid should have at least as many votes as him :).

Answer (score 7):

About the first section: This simulates the behavior of Mathematica a bit more closely than Kuba's answer, creating an additional RowBox. However, the choice of how general the different aspects of the solution are may be a bit odd. Kuba's answer feels cleaner.

Use the OPs definition of str. The following will generate an input cell where the comments are (still) present as comments.

```
store[str_String] := (Sow[str]; token);

CellPrint[Cell[#, "Input"]] &@
 BoxData[
  ReplacePart[#[[1]],
     MapThread[
      Rule, {Position[#[[1]], "token"], 
       Composition[RowBox, List] /@ #[[2, 1]]}]] &@
   Reap[ToBoxes@Map[Composition[store, ToString], str, {2, 2}]]]
```

**Format preserving alternative**

Suppose we start with the input cell

```
str = 
{{{"8.0,1034(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q *)"}, {"8.0,1035(*g opx \
ksp pl ilm liq q *)"}}, {{"8.0,886(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q  *)"}}}
```

We can give this a celltag by putting our cursor in the cell and doing Cell>Show Expression from the menu. The resulting cell will be the same as the cell printed by

```
Cell[BoxData[
    RowBox[{"str", "=", 
       RowBox[{"{", 
          RowBox[{
             RowBox[{"{", 
                RowBox[{

             RowBox[{"{", 
               "\"\<8.0,1034(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q *)\>\"", "}"}], 
             ",", 

             RowBox[{"{", 
               "\"\<8.0,1035(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q *)\>\"", 
               "}"}]}], "}"}], ",", 
             RowBox[{"{", 

           RowBox[{"{", 
             "\"\<8.0,886(*g opx ksp pl ilm liq q  *)\>\"", "}"}], 
           "}"}]}], 
          "}"}]}]], "Input", CellTags -> {"targetCell"}] // CellPrint
```

We can now do

```
NotebookRead[Cells[CellTags -> "targetCell"]] /. 
  x_String?(StringMatchQ[#, 
       "\"*" ~~ Verbatim["(*"] ~~ ___ ~~ Verbatim["*)\""]] &) :> 
   StringTake[x, {2, -2}] // CellPrint
```

to get a cell that is formatted in the same way as the cell with CellTag "targetCell", except for any formatting that may occur inside strings.

**Format ignoring option using strings**

Mr.Wizard hinted at a solution using strings, and Rm-rf gave the main code for this

```
CellPrint[Cell[#, "Input"]] &@
 First@MathLink`CallFrontEnd@
   UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[ToString[str], False]
```

Which seems nice for this question, especially as having comments in strings hints at the expression str being the result of some Import command by Mathematica, or that this expression is at least generated in some way. In this case you don't care about existing formatting and in case of Import maybe it is an option to do all parsing by `UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket`. Who knows

Comment: @geordie woops, I have added that.

Comment: Very nice. It works perfectly. I think I'll have to do some reading about cell expressions.. Many Thanks!

Comment: @geordie yay :), then I am glad. I have done this kind of thing before without any boxes (and comments for that matter), but that was not so nice. This was good practise for me :).

Comment: Perhaps you should look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/assign-variables-automatically-to-a-function/26079#26079) question. I was hoping to get `autofunc` to generate a cell expression but I have not yet the skills..

Comment: @geordie Ah yes, nice. I upvoted that question (which I don't do often) and favorited it. I wanted to present a solution yesterday but I had no time. I also saw your solution, but I don't like working with strings, I prefer held expressions. I always regret decisions like determining the scope of a variable. So I'm very interested in how we can do something like that afterwards :).

Comment: +1 Analizing the code was educational :) There are so many procedures packed in couple od lines. If I understand correctly, everything is based on fact that `CellPrint[Cell[#, "Input"]] &@ BoxData[RowBox[{"{expr(*comm*)}"}]]` gives us what We need. I do not really understand this. Please explain it and take a look on my "upgraded solution".

Comment: @Kuba I will get back to this after some sleep :). You are a good sport :)

Comment: You can save yourself the trouble of constructing the boxes by using `UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket`. For example, ``First@MathLink`CallFrontEnd@UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[s, False]`` where `s` is a string

Comment: @rm-rf thanks, after the discussion about parsing strings, I felt that that comment appear in an answer, so I put it in. Uff, I should stop. Cheers!