# How to convert comment in RowBox to DisplayForm string

Tags: boxes

```
ToExpression[RowBox[{"a","(*","what", "*)"}],StandardForm]
```

This conversion above ignores the commment content `(*what*)`

The result I expected is something like the `DisplayForm` below.

```
RowBox[{"a","(*","what","*)"}]//DisplayForm
```

[image]

Update: one of my test code, how to improve it, and not use (`StringReplace`) if possible.

```
RowBoxtoString[x_]:=StringReplace[
ToString[ToExpression[x/.RowBox[{"(*",t_,"*)"}]:>"CommentLeft"<>(StringJoin@@t)<>"ComentRight"],
StandardForm],
Shortest["CommentLeft"~~t__~~"ComentRight"]:>"(*"<>t<>"*)"]

RowBoxtoString[RowBox[{"(*","Comment Content","*)"}]]
(*Comment Content*)
```

Comment: Very closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26136/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way, with a couple of output methods :-

First, setting up a `RowBox` template, with some non-comment objects.  (The template is useful for setting up more complex `FullForm` expressions.)

```
Clear[a, b]
c = FullForm@ToBoxes[a == b]
```

> RowBox[List["a", "\[Equal", "b"]]

Now editing the `RowBox` parameters, (or substituting values into the `FullForm` object):

```
c[[1, 1, 2]] = "(*what*)";
c[[1, 1, 3]] = Sequence[];
c
```

> RowBox[List["a", "(`*what`*)"]]

`c` still has a `FullForm` wrapper at this point, so `First` is used to reach the `RowBox` object.

```
DisplayForm@First@c
```

> a(`*what`*)

Alternatively, displaying as regular output, (or as `"Input"`, ready for evaluation):

```
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData@First@c, "Output"]
```

> a(`*what`*)

Finally as a function :-

```
RowBoxtoString[x_, y_] := Module[{a, b, c},
  c = FullForm@ToBoxes[a == b];
  c[[1, 1, 1]] = x;
  c[[1, 1, 2]] = y;
  c[[1, 1, 3]] = Sequence[];
  CellPrint@Cell[BoxData@First@c, "Output"]]

RowBoxtoString["a", "(*what*)"]
```

> a(`*what`*)

Comment: fine, I like your usage of `Set` for `Boxes`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess commment is not expression, so use `NotebookWrite[nb, content]` may help.

```
NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], StringJoin @@ RowBox[{"a", "(*", "what", "*)"}]]
```

results: `a (*what*)` which a is still a symbol.

If you want the output to be a single string:

```
NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], 
  "\"" <> (StringJoin @@ RowBox[{"a", "(*", "what", "*)"}]) <> "\""]
```

results: `"a(*what*)"`

Comment: `"a (*what*)"` this is also one expected result.

Comment: @HyperGroups Updated, hope it helps.

Comment: Well,I need `ToExpression`, See my edit, better to not use `StringReplace` and make it suit for my original example.