# Converting an expression to function

Tags: functions, function-construction, expression-manipulation

I have the following problem. I current can automatically create the variable `positionPayload`, for instance:

```
positionPayload=2.x+3.t^2
```

I need, however, to automatically make `positionPayload` a function of `x` and `t`, i.e. do something like `positionPayload[x_,t_]`. To identify the variables present in `positionPayload`, I do:

```
variableList=DeleteDuplicates[Variables[positionPayload]]
```

However, how do I now write something to the effect of `positionPayload[variableList]` such that *Mathematica* now understands that `positionPayload` is a function of those variables?

#### Update

My question really is: how can I convert `positionPayload` into `positionPayload[x_,t_]` using the list `variableList`.

Comment: perhaps you're after SetDelayed : `positionPayload := 2.x+3.t^2`

Comment: @belisarius I am just looking for a way how I can write `f[a_,b_]` knowing the list `{a,b}`. `Apply[]` is not working....

Comment: Related: [(10067)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/convert-an-expression-to-a-function), [(31985)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31985/turn-expression-into-function)

Answer (score 5):

Not that I would recommend this, but anyway:

```
positionPayload = 2. x + 3. t^2;
variableList = Variables[positionPayload];
positionPayload = Function[Evaluate@variableList, Evaluate@positionPayload];
positionPayload[q, r]
(* 3. q^2 + 2. r *)
```

---

**Edit**

```
positionPayload = 2. x[1] + 3. t[3]^2;
variableList = Variables[positionPayload];
ul = Unique[ConstantArray[\[FormalT], Length@variableList]];
positionPayload = Function @@ {ul, positionPayload /. Thread[variableList -> ul]};
positionPayload[q, r]
(*3. q^2+2. r*)
```

Comment: It still doesn't quite work. This gives my `positionPayload[x,t]` while I need `positionPayload[x_,t_]`

Comment: @space_voyager It gives you `positionPayload = Function[{t,x},3. t^2+2. x]` which is exactly the same as `positionPayload[ t_, x_] := 3. t^2+2. x`

Comment: @space_voyager I have no idea what you mean.  It gives `Function[{t, x}, 3. t^2 + 2. x]`, which is a "pure function" instead of a transformation rule.  What is the practical difference in your use-case? (BTW, my idiomatic way to do the same thing would be `positionPayload = Function @@ {Variables[positionPayload], positionPayload}`. I don't believe `DeleteDuplicates` is necessary.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 You're right about `DeleteDuplicates`. I copied it in BM (Brainless Mode)

Comment: OK, I found the issue. This solution works, but my problem persists because in my actual code the variable `x` is `x[2]` (because I have multiple `x`'s and I need to distinguish between them). How do I do to  handle a variable with these "brackets"?

Comment: @space_voyager That is [something almost, but not quite entirely unlike what you asked above :)](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/734852-something-almost-but-not-quite-entirely-unlike-tea)

Comment: @belisarius I never thought the brackets would be the culprit. Your solution does work if I didn't have them...

Comment: @space_voyager The difference is quite fundamental in Mathematica: `x` is a `Symbol`, while `x[1]` isn't.

Comment: @space_voyager Check edit

Comment: @MichaelE2 Used your suggestion on my edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might try something like this, which makes pure functions, which means the variables used int the expression to converted only have to be clear at time `expToF` is called.

```
expToF[exp_, vars : {_Symbol ..}] :=
  With[{body = exp /. Thread[Rule[vars, Slot /@ Range @ Length[vars]]]},
    Function[body]]

Clear[x,t]
f = expToF[2. x + 3. t^2, {x, t}];
f[x,t]
```

> ```
> 3. t^2 + 2. x
> ```

Not limited to two variables.

```
Clear[x, y, z]
g = expToF[Sin[2 x] (1 - Cos[y]) E^z, {x, y, z}];
g[a, b, c]
```

> ```
> (E^c)(1 - Cos[b]) Sin[2 a]
> ```

It can even be used for somewhat weird things, like

```
Clear[x]
h = expToF[Style[x, 24, Bold, Red, "SR"], {x}]
h[1 + Sin[x]]
```

which produces

[image: funny]

Despite *Mathematica*'s funny formatting of the pure function returned by `expToF`, the returned function, as can be seen, works perfectly well.

#### Update

To handle the OP's revised question, I revise my definition definition of `expToF` to

```
expToF[exp_, vars : {(_Symbol | h_Symbol[_Integer]) ..}] :=
  With[{body = exp /. Thread[Rule[vars, Slot /@ Range @ Length[vars]]]},
    Function[body]]
```

then

```
Clear[x]
positionPayload = 2. x[1] + 3. x[2]^2;
positionPayload = expToF[positionPayload, {x[1], x[2]}];
positionPayload[q, r]
```

> ```
> 2. q + 3. r^2
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
positionPayload = 2. x + 3. t^2
(* 3. t^2 + 2. x *)

variableList = DeleteDuplicates[Variables[positionPayload]]
(* {t, x} *)

temp = positionPayload;
positionPayload =.
Evaluate[positionPayload @@ (Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ variableList)] := Evaluate@temp

Definition@positionPayload
(* positionPayload[t_, x_] := 3. t^2 + 2. x *)

positionPayload[q, r]
(* 3. q^2 + 2. r *)
```

Answer (score 2):

My one shot at answering this question:

```
Attributes[convert] = {HoldFirst};

convert[def_Symbol?ValueQ] :=
  With[{old = def, pats = Quiet[Sequence @@ Cases[Variables @ def, s_Symbol :> s_]]},
    ClearAll[def];
    def[pats] := old;
  ]
```

Test:

```
positionPayload = 2. x + 3. t^2;

convert[positionPayload]

?? positionPayload
```

> Global`positionPayload
>
> ```
> positionPayload[t_, x_] := 3. t^2 + 2. x
> ```

```
positionPayload[5, 7]
```

> ```
> 89.
> ```

I hope it helps.