# Turning an expression into a function inside another function

Tags: programming, scoping, assignment

Say I have an expression

```
g=Sin[q];
```

It is easy to turn it into a function, and to perform manipulations on this function (this and variants of this [were discussed many times](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31985/turn-expression-into-function) on this site):

```
f[q_] = g;
fprime = Derivative[1][f];
fprime[3]
(*Output: Cos[3]*)
```

However, if I want to pass `g` as an argument to a function that will do that, this no longer works:

```
calculateDerivativeAt3[func_] := Block[{f, fprime},
  f[q_] = func;
  fprime = Derivative[1][f];
  fprime[3]
]
calculateDerivativeAt3[Sin[q]]
(*Output: 0 *)
```

How can I make this work in a similar way? The ultimate goal is to pass an expression into a function, and in the function to perform various functional manipulations,  including derivatives, integrations, and more.

I'm pretty sure this question has an answer somewhere in this site, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Can't you define `calcDerAtq[func_, q_] := Derivative[1][func][q]` and use it as `calcDerAtq[Sin[#] Log[#^2/2] &, 10]` ?

Comment: I think you meant `f[x_] = g` (with `x` instead of a `q`).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Fixed this issue in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for your problem is the automatic renaming that *Mathematica* makes in cases where the names would clash. Let me give a very basic example (parenthesis for clarity; not required):

```
assign[rhs_] := (f[x_] := rhs)
```

What happens when you call `assign[x^2]` is that `rhs` contains the pattern variable `x` and *Mathematica* does a renaming so that no bad things happen.

```
assign[x^2];
?? f
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Do you see the difference between the renamed `x$` and the pure `x`? Now it is obvious why this happens

```
f[3]
(* x^2 *)
```

and of course it's the same in your example. This whole approach is not how you should do it and I would rather use an approach like the one suggested by belisarius (and think about whether you need to prevent `func` or `q` from evaluation!):

```
calcDerAtq[func_, q_] := Derivative[1][func][q]
```

Since we now found the underlying reason for your code failure, I hope it is clear what is **not a way to fix this issue** (although it works):

```
calculateDerivativeAt3[func_] := Block[{f, fprime},
  f[q_] = func;
  fprime = Derivative[1][f];
  fprime[3]
  ]
calculateDerivativeAt3[Sin[q$]]
(* Cos[3] *)
```

If you like to use your function as it is, there is as simple way to prevent renaming. When you replace the line

```
f[q_] = func;
```

by the line

```
(f[q_] = #) &[func];
```

*Mathematica* is not able to detect the name-clash and cannot rename the variable. After this, you will get

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the solution that you recommend **not** to use is the one I need. The solution with `calcDerAtq` is specific to derivatives. What if I want to integrate the result, or plug it in `NDSolve`?

Comment: @yohbs I have added a quick way how you can fix your function. Btw, this is not something you *could have known*. You'll learn which constructs will have surprising behavior and which won't. Look for instance [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tmS9r.png). A similar situation to yours, where the rhs injected by `With` changes everything.

Answer (score 2):

I gave a method for handling this kind of problem in this [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89875/3066). Here I show its application to your problem.

```
expToF[exp_, vars : {(_Symbol | h_Symbol[_Integer]) ..}] := 
  With[{body = exp /. Thread[Rule[vars, Slot /@ Range@Length[vars]]]}, 
    Function[body]]

calculateDerivativeAt[xpr_, var_, val_] := Derivative[1][expToF[xpr, {var}]][val]
Clear[q]; calculateDerivativeAt[Sin[q], q, 3]
```

> ```
> Cos[3]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how general this is, but it works here. Add another argument stating what the variable will be. Then replace the variable with a local variable inside your block.

```
calculateDerivativeAt3[func_, var_] := Block[
  {f, fprime, blkVar},
  f[blkVar_] = (func /. var -> blkVar);
  fprime = Derivative[1][f];
  fprime[3]
  ]
SetAttributes[calculateDerivativeAt3,HoldAll];
calculateDerivativeAt3[Sin[q], q]
```

This should give you the output you want. You'll want to set the attribute so the function still works if you happen to have an existing value for the variable you choose.